# TypeError: this.$cookies is undefined using vue-cookie

Tags: vue.js, cookies, vue-cookies

I'm trying use vue cookies, I made all the process to install it

`npm install vue-cookies --save`

and in my /resources/js/app.js I have

```
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
var VueCookie = require('vue-cookie');
Vue.use(VueCookie);
this.$cookies.set('test', 'Hello world!', 1);
```

so, when I load the page I give the next error

```
TypeError: this.$cookies is undefined
```

I tried to solve this in different ways like:

```
this.$cookies.set(...)
Vue.$cookies.set(...)
this.$cookie.set(...)
Vue.$cookies.set(...)
window.$cookies.set(...)
window.$cookie.set(...)
Vue.prototype.$cookie = VueCookie;
```

but nothing work and always give the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

You're using `this.$cookies` outside the Vue context, where `this` is probably `window`.

To resolve the issue, replace `this.$cookies` with `Vue.$cookies` to set a global cookie, or move `this.$cookies` to a component method/hook.

*Example usage based on the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies):*

```js
//...
Vue.use(VueCookies)

// set global cookie
Vue.$cookies.set('theme', 'default');

// set cookie from Vue context
new Vue({
  mounted() {
    this.$cookies.set('theme', 'default');
  }
})
```

Comment: I have `this.$cookies.set('theme', 'default');` inside a component, specific in the mounted method but continues show the same error

Comment: and when  I use `Vue.$cookies` give me `Vue.$cookies is undefined`